# How to stop Git from tracking language percentage of frameworks?

Tags: github

As you probably know, you can see the percentage of each language used inside a repo on GitHub.

My repository was more than 90% written in Swift, but when I added an external framework (OpenEars), Swift suddenly became 2.8% since the framework is written in other languages and it is big.

Is there a way to stop GitHub from tracking the language of the framework? Or is there a way to convert the framework in something like a binary code in order to stop GitHub from tracking its language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify this behaviour with .gitattributes file:

```
$ cat .gitattributes
special-vendored-path/* linguist-vendored
(your framework) linguist-vendored=false
```

You can follow this [url](https://github.com/github/linguist#vendored-code) for more info.